# How do I get the referrer of a new link opening via Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension, google-plus

I'm trying to make a utility chrome extension for myself to automatically change URLs from plus.google.com/XXXX to plus.google.com/u/1/XXXX in webpages from all websites excluding plus.google.com itself. I have successfully made this however, it doesn't work on all websites especially since I'm using the innerHTML and changing the URLs from there.

So what I had in mind was catch the URL while it is loading and change it midway. However, I want to know which referrer it came from because if it was clicked from within plus.google.com itself then I **don't** want to do anything with it. I just want to use the URL changing thing  for links outside of plus.google.com.

How can I go about doing that with my Chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something similar in concept through [content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) and injecting the script on the target page. This doesn't change the links in pages but instead forwards the user to a new URL as long as it's not getting referred from a specific host. I did something like this in a file called script.js:

```
if (document.referrer != "") // Check if referrer isn't empty
{
  var referringURL = document.referrer;
  var referrerArray = referringURL.split('/'); // Split the referrer into an array.

  if (referrerArray[2] != "plus.google.com") // Grab the hostname and compare
  {
    location.replace("https://plus.google.com/u/1/"+referrerArray[3]); // Redirect with XXXX
  }
}
```

And something similar to this will be in the manifest:

```
  "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": [
          "https://plus.google.com/*",
          "http://plus.google.com/*"
       ],
       "js": ["script.js"]
     }
  ]
```

I haven't tested this specific code but it's quite similar to what I used which worked quite well. It's not very elegant, I know, so I have since switched to webRequest/webRequestBlocking which I think is better but I'm still trying to figure out how to do exclusions via referrers. No luck on that part yet, unfortunately.

Comment: Nice! Will check this out as soon as I get on a computer.